# React-Suspense no se ejecuta al ponerlo en layout.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Estoy intentando hacer una pantalla de carga en mi proyecto para cuando redirecciono entre páginas, esto dado que los componentes de estas tienen llamados a API's que tardan cierto tiempo, incluí un Suspense en el layout.tsx para que el footer también se oculte durante la pantalla de carga, pero no funciona, es mi primera vez usando Suspense así que disculpen.

```
"use client"
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes"
import { Suspense } from 'react';


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Suspense fallback={<div><h1>Loading...</h1></div>}>
      <body>
      <ThemeProvider enableSystem={true} attribute="class">
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </Suspense>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Aviso que los children en todos los casos son componentes clientes que tienen una async function dentro del export default function, la async function ejecuta el llamado desde un componente del servidor que tiene el código del fetch.

Comment: Parece que la directiva "use client" no debería ir en el RootLayout, en ese componente no se ve nada de interactividad entre el DOM y JS, cada componente hijo que agregue interactividad DOM/JS debería llevar su propia directiva "use client", agrega un ejemplo de el componente y su llamada fetch, por otro lado así como tienes `Suspense` deberías ver un error `JSX closing tag for html`, tienes que encerrar el componente que hace la llamada API con Suspense